# Reduce row count int data.frame by meaning range of row

Tags: r, dataframe, split, reduce

I have a data.frame with 2 columns a, b, which are percentage. My objective is to draw each line as a 2 part barplot, with height = 100%

```
V1    V2 
40    60
10    90 
25    75 
50    50
```

I have many rows, more than 20000. I can't plot them. So, My idea is to reduce my dataframe by meaning row. For instance, the dataframe above can be reduce by 2 and become :

```
V1    V2 
25    75
37.5   62.5
```

How can I do that ? 
Or you may have another idea, to draw my plot using something else than barplot ?

They

Comment: What is your rule for row reduction above? It is not clear to me.

Comment: That depends on the data you have and what they represent. What do the rows mean? You might try and make a bean plot if they're important. If not, why not summarise the data with a simple boxplot (which would be more informative than your summarising barplot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have over 20000 rows and you want to draw a line between each depicting the change in percentages between a and b, you will have over 20000 lines overlapping with each other, this will produce a meaningless plot, too messy to interpret and you will have overplotting.

What is probably better is to plot the means with error bars, or to have 2 boxplots.

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(40,10,25,50), v2=c(60,90,75,50))
boxplot(df)
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq8Z6.png)